# chroot fails with --userspec when chroot is i686

Tags: arch-linux, users, chroot

I'm experiencing a problem with `chroot`...

I'm running on Arch Linux x86_64.

I have a 64 bit chroot and a 32 bit chroot. They are identical except that one is 32 bit and one is 64 bit.

I can enter either of them using `chroot /path/to/chroot`. No problems.

If I want to do that as a specific user the command is:

```
chroot --userspec=user:group /path/to/chroot
```

This also works fine for the 64 bit chroot. However it fails for the 32 bit chroot.  It fails with status 125 and the message `chroot: invalid user`

Also, doing `chroot --userspec=uid:gid /path/to/chroot` works fine in both 32 and 64 bit chroots (`uid` and `gid` are the numeric ids of the required user and group).

I don't know if I am doing something wrong. is there anyone who has a 32 bit chroot and can see if the above can be reproduced ?

All commands are issued as root. The user and group used for the userspec argument need to be defined inside the chroot.

Or if I am missing something please I would appreciate knowing where I am going wrong.

Update: I am using a work around for this problem. Assuming `$user` has the `user:group` I want (e.g. `john:users`), I do this:

```
u=$(echo $user | awk -F ":" '{print $1}')
g=$(echo $user | awk -F ":" '{print $2}')
uid=$(grep $u /opt/chroot32/etc/passwd | awk -F ":" '{print $3}')
gid=$(grep $g /opt/chroot32/etc/group  | awk -F ":" '{print $3}')
echo "Using $uid:$gid in place of $user"
chroot --userspec="$uid:$gid" /opt/chroot32
```

This works - it looks up the desired `user:group` inside the chroot's passwd and group files and then uses those for the chroot. And the above workaround is not necessary when accessing a 64 bit chroot.

Comment: I asked the coreutils team about this and I have tested a patch to chroot that fixes the problem. I don't as of yet know if/when it will be released.

Comment: Which patch? does it work? Feel free to answer your own question.

Comment: I thought I had answered my own question. Like I said, I was sent a patch by coreutils which I applied and it fixed the problem. I thought I had said that ;) There is no "official patch" and they haven't said anything about if/when there will be one. I haven't posted the patch as it was given to me as "tentative". As soon as I hear more I will update it here.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot enter a chroot with a username that is not known to the target chroot environment. Copy all required file for user authentication to each chroot: `/etc/passwd`, `/etc/shadow`, `/etc/nsswitch.conf`, and, eventually all files in `/etc/pam.d/*`.
I

Comment: I had already covered that point in my original question where I said "The user and group used for the userspec argument need to be defined inside the chroot."

Comment: You are right.I did not correctly understood that sentence. Maybe you could also try a workaround like preceding your commands with a `su --command 'sg $group -c "$command"' $user` or write a wrapper script that runs inside the chroot.